# if statements and optionals in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a difference between something like

```
if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

and just checking if it is = nil

```
if error != nil {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

if I want to check if error has a value? Think of firebase's creating user function.

Comment: did you check the output? is it different?

Comment: Did you try the second piece of code? It probably won't compile as-is.

Comment: i did not check any code, because I was watching  tutorial on firebase working with signing users and was just wondering if this was possible and googled it and there was no other questions on stack that I could see.

Comment: It's best to try code and experiment with it a bit before posting a question. You might figure it out yourself in the process. You may at least learn something too. Besides, you should post code that actually works to get the best help.

Comment: thanks rmaddy, thats true and will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The `if let` statement allows you to bind the value of `error` to a variable if it is non-nil and use it in the block. If `maybeError` is of type `Error?`, when you do:

```
if let error = maybeError {
    /* block contents */
}
```

the type of `error` will be `Error` within the block - ie: It won't be an optional anymore. If you just do a nil-check using `if`, `error` will still be of type `Error?` within the block. So the code that would actually be equivalent to your first snippet would be:

```
if error != nil {
    print(error!.localizedDescription)
}
```

(Your second snippet, as it is, won't compile, as you're trying to get the `localizedDescription` variable of an `Error?` object, which has no such property)

By the way, in case you haven't seen it before, the `!.` thing is the *unwrap operator*. It runs the method on the object if the object is non-nil, but it crashes in case the object is nil. In this case, you generally know it won't crash. (But this might not actually be safe depending on where and how you use it - check @rmaddy's comment)

Comment: You end your answer with *"In this case, you know it won't crash."*. This isn't true. Another thread could set `error` to `nil` just after the `if error != nil` line is performed. Then the use of `error!` will cause a crash. If `error` is a local variable then you should be safe. But in general, be careful with `if something != nil` followed by `something!`. Not safe in general in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: rmaddy you can always answer if you want to.

Comment: @GavinWolfeStudentHBHS I have nothing to add that hasn't been discussed many times in many other similar questions on these topics.

Answer (score 0):

In the first, `error` is now a non-optional type, so you can use `.`.  This is also idiomatic -- it more clearly shows what you are trying to do.

In the second, you would need to use `?.` to look at `error`'s properties (your code won't compile because you haven't done that).